# Miner APIs are not found in web3.js package

Tags: web3js, dapp-development

How can I start and stop miner( `miner.start()`, `miner.stop()`) from my DApp if Miner APIs are available in web3.js package? I am using `web3 v0.20.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sue Web3Admin, which extends web3 to give more methods regarding many ethereum tools.

here is their GitHub : https://github.com/DecentricCorp/web3admin